# Why neutrino's mass states are assumed to share the same momentum?

Tags: momentum, mass, neutrinos

In derivation of two-neutrino oscillation probability, it was assumed that the mass states have the same momentum. Why is that?

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXzur-2hbkI&t=115s&ab_channel=MITOpenCourseWare

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/399767/) and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21351/). It's easier to assume they have the same energy, but it makes no [practical difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation#Propagation_and_interference).

Comment: [Lipkin's helpful paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physletb.2006.09.054).

Comment: Momentum and energy conservation. These fields can't just "magically" acquire a different energy or momentum. If we would observe such a change, then we would have to find another field that they interact with.